# datepicker not working on cloned rows

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i found this zebra datepicker but my problem is that dates are not functional on cloned rows ... here is my fiddle code: 
html

```
 <DIV id="mainContent_pnlEmploymentHistory">
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="value.php">
<TABLE id="dataTable">
  <TBODY>
  <TR>
    <TD style="width: 310px; height: 20px; text-align: center;">Name of Employer</TD>
    <TD style="width: 430px; height: 20px; text-align: center;"> Employer Address</TD>
    <TD style="width: 150px; height: 20px; text-align: center;">FROM</TD>
    <TD style="width: 150px; height: 20px; text-align: center;">TO</TD></TR>
  <TR class="row_to_clone_fw_emp">
    <TD style="width: 310px; height: 20px; text-align: center;">
      <input type="text" id="fwemployer" name="fwemployer[]" style="width:300px"/>
    </TD>
    <TD style="width: 430px; height: 20px; text-align: center;">
    <input type="text" id="fwempaddress" name="fwempaddress[]" style="width:100%"/></TD>
    <TD>
    <input id="datepicker-example7-start" type="text" name="datefrom[]"/></TD>
    <TD>
    <input id="datepicker-example7-end" type="text"  name="dateto[]"/></TD>

  </TR>
      </TBODY>
</TABLE>
    <table>
  <tr>
<td colspan="3" align="right"><INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" id="addrow" onclick="addRowfwemp(); return false;"/></td>
<td  colspan="4" align="right"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</DIV>
```

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#datepicker-example7-start').Zebra_DatePicker({
        direction: false,
        pair: $('#datepicker-example7-end')
    });

    $('#datepicker-example7-end').Zebra_DatePicker({
        direction: true
    });

});

$(document).ready(function(){
$( "#addrow" ).click(function() {

  var zdp = $('#datepicker-example7-start').data('Zebra_DatePicker');
  var zdp1 = $('#datepicker-example7-end').data('Zebra_DatePicker');
zdp.destroy();
zdp1.destroy();
});
});

function addRowfwemp() {
    /* Declare variables */
    var elements, templateRow, rowCount, row, className, newRow, element;
    var i, s, t;

    /* Get and count all "tr" elements with class="row".    The last one will
     * be serve as a template. */
    if (!document.getElementsByTagName)
        return false; /* DOM not supported */
    elements = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    templateRow = null;
    rowCount = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        row = elements.item(i);

        /* Get the "class" attribute of the row. */
        className = null;
        if (row.getAttribute)
            className = row.getAttribute('class');
        if (className === null && row.attributes) {    // MSIE 5
            /* getAttribute('class') always returns null on MSIE 5, and
             * row.attributes doesn't work on Firefox 1.0.    Go figure. */
            className = row.attributes['class'];
            if (className && typeof(className) === 'object' && className.value) {
                // MSIE 6
                className = className.value;
            }
        } 

        /* This is not one of the rows we're looking for.    Move along. */
        if (className !== "row_to_clone_fw_emp")
            continue;

        /* This *is* a row we're looking for. */
        templateRow = row;
        rowCount++;
    }
    if (templateRow === null)
        return false; /* Couldn't find a template row. */

    /* Make a copy of the template row */
    newRow = templateRow.cloneNode(true);

    /* Change the form variables e.g. price[x] -> price[rowCount] */
    elements = newRow.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        element = elements.item(i);
        s = null;
        s = element.getAttribute("name");
        if (s === null)
            continue;
        t = s.split("[");
        if (t.length < 2)
            continue;
        s = t[0] + "[" + rowCount.toString() + "]";
        element.setAttribute("name", s);
        element.value = "";
    }

    /* Add the newly-created row to the table */
    templateRow.parentNode.appendChild(newRow);
    return true;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jakecruz011/ZvsZm/ ... it might be a little broken since i cant upload all external resources but definitely the cloning methods and how datepicker is called is in there ...

the original code can be found here (exxample 7): http://stefangabos.ro/jquery/zebra-datepicker/

files on github is downloadable here: https://github.com/stefangabos/Zebra_Datepicker/

thanks so much for the help! would be much appreciated ...

Comment: You need to rebind the cloned rows

Comment: tnx for that, how do i do that? i tried calling the datepicker again after destroy method but it only shows the calendar icon on the following rows but not clickable `code`  $('#datepicker-example7-start').Zebra_DatePicker({
        direction: false,
        pair: $('#datepicker-example7-end')
    });

    $('#datepicker-example7-end').Zebra_DatePicker({
        direction: true
    });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the `datepicker` function again, after append the new elements to `DOM`

I would suggest you to add a common class for the datepicker input fields.

```
<TD>
  <input id="datepicker-example7-start" type="text" name="datefrom[]" class="dp-start"/>
</TD>
<TD>
  <input id="datepicker-example7-end" type="text"  name="dateto[]"  class="dp-end"/>
</TD>
```

and call the datepicker function like this just after append the new row.

```
$('.dp-start:last').Zebra_DatePicker({
    direction: false,
    pair: $('.dp-end:last')
});

$('.dp-end:last').Zebra_DatePicker({
    direction: true
});
```

I have not tried this. Hope it will work.

Comment: could u help me by illustrating your idea thru the scripts above? thanks. i already destroyed the plugin once "addrow" button is clicked then call the clone function again.  `$( "#addrow" ).click(function() {

  var zdp = $('#datepicker-example7-start').data('Zebra_DatePicker');
  var zdp1 = $('#datepicker-example7-end').data('Zebra_DatePicker');
zdp.destroy();
zdp1.destroy();`

Comment: @jake: Updated the answer. Please check

Comment: thank u @nauphal ... your idea rocks, i did that but i used id and did not work , never thought class can make it ... thank u so much ... i called the datepicker onload then called it again after appendchild ...  there is just a little glitch, the datepicker is not loaded if calendar icon is clicked, you need to click the inputbox itself not the calendar icon